# Is it possible to clone a Google analytics account to another GA account

Tags: google-analytics

I have a google account from which my Admin access was removed, now the person is asking me to pay up for my data.
Is there a way for me to export all the data I have from my old account and import it to a new account.
currently I have "editor" access to the old account
If not is there any other way for me to get my account data

Answer (score 0):

> I have a google account from which my Admin access was removed, now the person is asking me to pay up for my data.

This is going to be your best options.

> Is there a way for me to export all the data I have from my old account and import it to a new account.

You could use the google analytics api to extract your data but inserting new data will not be inserted using the old dates. Hits in Google analytics are recorded for the most part when they come in.  You can set an offset but its only a matter of hours. You wont be able to rebuild the entire system.

> currently I have "editor" access to the old account If not is there any other way for me to get my account data

if you have a google analytics 360 account you could export it into big query.

There is really no other way to get your data back besides them giving you admin access.